# How to add numbers in log file

Tags: shell-script, files

I want to get a sum of `Messages` values(427852+ 403553+ 385167 ) from a log file like below. I have tried with cut and awk, but no luck.

```
2019-08-27 21:52:49 INFO  =- Reporting Cycle:10000 Lines:427852 Messages: 427852 IO_time:1391 Active Threads: 3
2019-08-27 21:52:59 INFO  =- Reporting Cycle:10000 Lines:403553 Messages: 403553 IO_time:1212 Active Threads: 3
2019-08-27 21:53:09 INFO  =- Reporting Cycle:10000 Lines:385167 Messages: 385167 IO_time:1200 Active Threads: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the sum of the 9th fields of your file (the 9th field is the one after `Messages:` in your example), you can do:

```
$ awk '{k+=$9}END{print k}' file
1216572
```

If the fields can change or if there isn't actually a space after `Messages:` (none of the other fields seem to have that), you can extract the number after messages and then sum it:

```
$ grep -oP 'Messages:\s*\K\d+' file | awk '{k+=$1}END{print k}' 
1216572
```

The above requires GNU `grep`, if you don't have that, you could always use `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne '/Messages:\s*(\d+)/; $k+=$1; END{print $k}' file
1216572
```